# Recursively delete all files named NET_Connections* that contain a specific string

Tags: linux, file, shell

I need to find a way to delete all files from a folder and it's sub folders with the filename "NET_Connections*", but only those that have a certain string in the file content (e.g. "TCP_Connections").

At the moment, I have something like this:

```
find . -type f -name "NET_Connections*" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

How could I check the content between `find . -type f -name "NET_Connections*"` and `-exec rm -f {} \;`

Thanks alot!

Grtz

Willem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\rm -f $(find . -type f -name "NET_Connections*" | xargs grep -l TCP_Connections | sed -r 's/\.[[:alnum:]]+$/*/')
```

- find command - will find the file with name like NET_Connections
- grep -l - will print just the file names containing TCP_Connections.
- \rm -f - forcefully remove the file found by grep.
- sed - replace extension with * so it deletes all the file like NET_Connections* that would include rrd and xml.

*You could do -exec grep as well instead of pipe.

Comment: Hey it works fine, but i seem to have another request (sorry for that). The server I'm executing this on is a Nagios server and the folder /usr/local/nagios/share/perfdata THis folder contains a directory for each Nagios host and in this directory I have two files for each service. In the case of NET_Connections, I have a NET_Connections.xml and a NET_Connections.rrd

Your solution will only delete NET_Connections.xml , the problem is that NET_Connections.rrd does not contain the string but also needs to be deleted if thr string is found in NET_Connections.xml.

Comment: I guess I'll write a Bash cript for that. :)

Comment: of course not. I have modified the command above. Hope it helps.